# How do install the Live Share Extension Pack?

Tags: azure, soundcloud, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-liveshare

In Windows 10 64 PC, how do I live monitor music tracks singing along to artiphon recorded music tracks to add vocal tracks to music mixes in music composition projects?

- https://prod.liveshare.vsengsaas.visualstudio.com/join?2A5529A01D5F8FD00E4C33FF254BFA600F7F
- https://dev.azure.com/StephenRichards/Artiphon%20Microphone%20Track%20Mix%20Record%20Live%20Monitor
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery

```
using System;
namespace myApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }   Console.WriteLine("The current time is " + DateTime.Now);

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think Microsoft Quantum Development Kit is going to help you with music-related projects. You might want to remove it from the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: This seems way too broad a question. Please try to ask something specific.